# Simulate An Error Correction Model with Multiple Cointegrating Vectors

Tags: python, simulation, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

Simulating multiple time series with a single cointegrating vector can be done as follows:

$S_t = S_{t-1} - \kappa (S_{t-1} \cdot P-\mu) \Delta t + \epsilon_t\sqrt{\Delta t} $

where the noise $\epsilon$ and weights matrix $P$ are defined as

\begin{align}\epsilon_t \sim N(0, \Sigma) \quad\text{and}\quad P = \begin{bmatrix} {w_1}/{w_1} & {w_2}/{w_1} & {w_3}/{w_1}\\ 
{w_1}/{w_2} & {w_2}/{w_2} & {w_3}/{w_2}\\
{w_1}/{w_3} & {w_2}/{w_3} & {w_3}/{w_3}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
and the single cointegrating vector $\textbf{w} = [w_1,w_2,w_3]$

The above can be implemented in Python easily:

```
import numpy as np

w = [1,-0.7,-0.3]
N = 1000
S = np.ones([N,len(w)])*2000
kappa = 20
sigma = 20
dt = 1/N
corr = 0.9
C = np.ones([len(w),len(w)])*corr+(1-corr)*np.eye(len(w))
for t in range(1,N):
    eps = np.random.multivariate_normal([0]*len(w),C)
    for i in range(len(w)):
        si = 0
        for j in range(len(w)):
            si += w[j]/w[i]*S[t-1,j]
        S[t,i] = S[t-1,i] - kappa*dt*si + sigma**2*np.sqrt(dt)*eps[i]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(15,5), gridspec_kw={'hspace':0.02})
ax[0].plot(S)
ax[1].plot(S.dot(w))
```

Which produces:
[image: Multivariate ECM with one cointegrating vector]

What is the appropriate way to simulate 3 time series with **two** cointegrating vectors? ie given weights $\textbf{w}_1$ and $\textbf{w}_2$ such that $S\cdot \textbf{w}_1 \sim I(0)$ and $S\cdot \textbf{w}_2 \sim I(0)$

Comment: Are you only interested in continuous time, or is discrete time also fine?

Comment: Ideally something that can be implemented programatically, so discrete time would likely be best. It'd be great to see the continuous time approach also.

Comment: I had not seen a continuous-time VECM before, so I find it curious. I wonder how to interpret $t$: it seems it is serving two conflicting purposes – as an index for $S$ and as the time increment between $S_t$ and $S_{t-1}$, but I guess I am misunderstanding the notation.

Comment: I wonder if instead of time indices $t$ and $t-1$ you should not have $\tau$ and $\tau-dt$ or something like that.